# Java For loop is looping before my input is being asked for

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

When I run my program my for loop outputs the line "Enter a game score?" twice before I am able to input sometimes, have a made a silly error while constructing it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {

public static void main (String[] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your name?");   
    String playername = scan.nextLine();


    System.out.println("How many games will you be entering?"); 
    int numofgames = scan.nextInt();

    /* Creating the arrays*/
    String[] game = new String[numofgames];
    int[] scores = new int [numofgames];
    int[] mins = new int [numofgames];

    /* Creating a temp array to store the game data before splitting*/
    String[] temparray = new String[numofgames];

    /*Getting the users game data and storing it into the temp array*/
    for (int count=1; count <= numofgames; count++){
        System.out.println("Enter a game score?(Game name:Scores:Mins)");
                temparray[count] = scan.nextLine();


    }}}
```

Comment: Please enter valid compileable code.

Answer (score 0):

The function `scan.nextInt()` does not discard the newline character after you hit 'Enter'. So it stays in the buffer and is read when `scan.nextLine()` is called. Just empty the buffer after scan.nextInt()

```
int numofgames = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); // remove newline from buffer
```

You should also fix your loop boundaries:

```
for (int count=0; count < numofgames; count++) {
...
}
```